# Libgdx multiple enemies

Tags: java, arrays, object, libgdx

I am creating a game where a player has to dodge enemies, now that works fine with one enemy. But how do i create like an array of enemies to spawn them constantly? Here is the class/object i want to create multiple objects of:

```
public class Spike extends MoveEntity 
{
    public Spike(float speed, float rotation, float width, float height,    Vector2 position) 
    {
        super(speed, rotation, width, height, position);
    }

    void move(float delta) 
    {

    }

    public void update() 
    {
        position.y -= 3;
    }

}
```

And here is how I render it (just one enemy):

```
sb.draw(sp_bg5, s.getPosition().x, s.getPosition().y, s.getWidth() / 2, s.getHeight() / 2, s.getWidth(), s.getHeight(), 1, 1, 0);
```

Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a list (specifically, a java.util.LinkedList). You can create one like this:

```
LinkedList<Spike> enemies = new LinkedList<Spike>();
```

and add enemies in like this:

```
enemies.add(new Spike(speed, rotation, width, height, position);
```

and finally draw them like this:

```
for (Spike s : enemies) {
    sb.draw(sp_bg5, s.getPosition().x, s.getPosition().y, s.getWidth() / 2, s.getHeight() / 2, s.getWidth(), s.getHeight(), 1, 1, 0);
}
```

It will get more complicated if you want to de-spawn them, however. Java won't let you modify a list normally while you're iterating through it. You will have to use a special iterator for this:

```
ListIterator<Spike> it = enemies.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Spike s = it.next();
    if (s.shouldBeRemoved()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

and you could of course replace shouldBeRemoved with whatever check is necessary.

Comment: When i tried this it terminated and i got exit value 1, says error on line 125 LwjglApplication.

Comment: @Dumbostyle could you specify what error you are getting? Also, maybe post the new code including the line which produces the error.